# How can I remove NAs when both columns are missing only?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a df in R as follows:

```
ID    Age   Score1     Score2      
2      22    12           NA
3      19    11           22
4      20    NA           NA
1      21    NA           20
```

Now I want to only remove the rows where both Score 1 and Score 2 is missing (i.e. 3rd row)

Comment: `df %>% filter(!is.na(Score1) | !is.na(Score2))`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter it like this:

```
df <- read.table(head=T, text="ID    Age   Score1     Score2      
2      22    12           NA
3      19    11           22
4      20    NA           NA
1      21    NA           20")
df[!(is.na(df$Score1) & is.na(df$Score2)), ]
#   ID Age Score1 Score2
# 1  2  22     12     NA
# 2  3  19     11     22
# 4  1  21     NA     20
```

I.e. take rows where there's not (`!`) `Score1` missing and (`&`) `Score2` missing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `rowSums`

```
df1[ rowSums(is.na(df1[grep("Score", names(df1))])) < 2,]
```

---

Or another option with `base R`

```
df1[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[grep("Score", names(df1))], is.na)),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), Age = c(22L, 19L, 20L, 
 21L), Score1 = c(12L, 11L, NA, NA), Score2 = c(NA, 22L, NA, 20L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two version with `dplyr` which can be extended to many columns with prefix "Score".

Using `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Score")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))

#  ID Age Score1 Score2
#1  2  22     12     NA
#2  3  19     11     22
#3  1  21     NA     20
```

and `filter_if`

```
df %>% filter_if(startsWith(names(.),"Score"), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

---

A base R version with `apply`

```
df[apply(!is.na(df[startsWith(names(df),"Score")]), 1, any), ]
```